# Generate bitcoin address from public key file

Tags: address, openssl

Is there a way to generate a bitcoin address from public key with openssl command line ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Which kind of address do you want?

Assuming that you have compressed public key(`compressed_public_key.txt`), to generate `P2PKH` you can use these commands (hash160 and encoding with base58)

```
  ADDR_RIPEMD160=$(printf $(cat compressed_public_key.txt | xxd -r -p | openssl sha256| sed 's/^.* //') |xxd -r -p | openssl ripemd160 | sed 's/^.* //')
  ADDR=`printf $VERSION_PREFIX_ADDRESS$ADDR_RIPEMD160 | xxd -p -r | base58 -c`
  echo $ADDR
```

Where `$VERSION_PREFIX_ADDRESS` for P2PKH addresss are `0x00` for mainnet or `0x6F` for testnet (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes)

Comment: I want an address for receiving bitcoin

Comment: Which kind of address? P2PKH or P2SH or Native segwit or P2SH-embed segwit?

Comment: I don't really know. There are multiple kind of addresses for receiving bitcoins ?

Comment: Multiply kind of script.

Comment: check this link bob https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use openssl for generation of a bitcoin address from a public key, unfortunately. Bitcoin addresses require base58, bech32 or bech32m encoding which are not supported by OpenSSL.